# R: How to find specific Summary Statistics from Dataset?

Tags: r, statistics, subset, mean, summary

I want to find the median/mean/range GDP of a specific Region from my dataset.
For the summary of all Regions (Africa, Asia, Europe etc.) I put:

```
summary(data$GDP, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This displays all summary statistics of the GDP for all regions. However, I want only only regions summary statistics e.g. Africa's mean,median,quartile, or Europe. Those are the names of the region so those would be used.

Comment: `summary(data[data$region == "Africa", ])`

Comment: `tapply(data$GDP, data$region, summary)`